# TypeError: barh() got multiple values for argument 'width'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a graph, which was previously vertical... I'm trying to make it horizontal. What happens is that I get an error:

> TypeError: barh () got multiple values for argument 'width'.

Could anyone help?

```
barWidth = 1
plt.barh(r, bars1, color='#7f6d5f', edgecolor='white', width=barWidth, label="Lasso")
plt.barh(r, bars2, bottom=bars1, color='#557f2d', edgecolor='white', width=barWidth, label="Random Forest")
plt.barh(r, bars3, bottom=bars, color='#2d7f5e', edgecolor='white', width=barWidth, label="Decision Tree")
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? Also a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few things wrong:

- you can not give the width to the horizontal bars, you already set the width with the second parameter of `barh`; you need to set the height instead
- similarly, there is no bottom, you need to set the left
- finally, to get everything well positioned, for the third bars you need the sum of the previous two: `left=bars1+bars2` (or use a separate variable for the cumulated widths)

Some example code to show how it could work:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 5
r = range(N)
bars1 = np.random.binomial(20, .7, N)
bars2 = np.random.binomial(20, .5, N)
bars3 = np.random.binomial(20, .4, N)

colors = ['#7f6d5f', '#557f2d', '#2d7f5e']
labels = ["Lasso", "Random Forest", "Decision Tree"]

barWidth = 1
lefts = 0
for bars, col, label in zip([bars1, bars2, bars3], colors, labels):
    plt.barh(r, bars, left=lefts, color=col, edgecolor='white', height=barWidth, label=label)
    lefts += bars
plt.legend()
plt.ylim(-0.5, len(bars) - 0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: sample]